# Debug Build Variant can't start due to sqliteexception

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I cannot start the debug build variant anymore, the release one does work though. It throws an SQLiteException when i try to start my App. It worked like a charm before, the problem occured (iirc) when i updated the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 28 (Android 9) from 27, since then i can't use debug anymore. What do i have to do to get my debug mode running again?

I already tried completely wiping the app from my phone, tried using an emulator and tried clean and rebuild. My co-worker can still use the debug Mode, so i am pretty sure it's a local problem.

The important part of the stacktrace coming up when trying to start the app:

```
 (...)
    Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: DSEARCHES (Sqlite code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM DSEARCHES WHERE MARKET = ?, (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
 (...)
```

Since it was requested: My Database "Dsearches" extends SugarRecord by just a toString, i havnt written anything at all in there. The problem causing code is (Note that this line is performed in an AsyncTask):

```java
List<Dsearches> dsearches = MyApp.get().getDsearchesForCurrentMarket();
```

and the getDsearchesForCurrentMarket method:

```java
public List<Dsearches> getDsearchesForCurrentMarket() {
        return Dsearches.find(Dsearches.class, "MARKET = ?", getCurrentMarket());
    }
```

Dsearches Class:

```java
public class Dsearches extends SugarRecord{

    public String market;
    public String label;
    public String startDate;
    @Ignore
    public int count = 0;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String result = label + "\n";
        if(count > 0) {
            result += "Es wurden " + count + " neue Jobs gefunden.";
        } else {
            result += "Wir informieren Sie, sobald neue Jobs gefunden \nwurden.";
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

The full stacktrace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: de.jobware.app.debug, PID: 31687
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:246)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1187)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: DSEARCHES (Sqlite code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM DSEARCHES WHERE MARKET = ?, (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:948)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:559)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:603)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:63)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1493)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1335)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1206)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1412)
        at com.orm.SugarRecord.find(SugarRecord.java:201)
        at com.orm.SugarRecord.find(SugarRecord.java:187)
        at de.jobware.jana.JobwareApp.getDsearchesForCurrentMarket(MyApp.java:256)
        at de.jobware.jana.activity.StartActivity$3.doInBackground(StartActivity.java:133)
        at de.jobware.jana.activity.StartActivity$3.doInBackground(StartActivity.java:113)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:246) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1187) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
```

Sugar Record is a given Database implementation, downloadable
[here](https://satyan.github.io/sugar/index.html).

Comment: Post how you implemented database initialization and also the code block causing the error with complete log stack trace.

Comment: Alright i did, hope it helps :)

Comment: Please add code of `Dsearches` class and Room database builder.

Comment: What is the room database builder? cant find any of that in the project